# How do I display the function the_content in this loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I have this loop in my wordpress site which displays the latest posts with their titles, I want to display the post content after the title. I normally retrieve it with the function get_the_content but I jkeep breaking the whole page in all kind of ways, I'm very new to php and have little idea of how to add anything to the loop. This is the loop:

```
     while ( $q_query->have_posts() )
     {

        $q_query->next_post();
        $question = get_post($q_query->post);
        $loophtml = $loophtml . "<li><span class='list-question-title'>" . "<a class='list-answer-link' href='" . get_permalink($question->ID) ."'>" . $question->post_title . "</a></span>";
        $loophtml = $loophtml . "<span class='list-number-answers'>" . get_comments_number($question->ID) . " comentarios</span>&nbsp;&#183;&nbsp<a href='" . get_permalink($question->ID) ."'>Comentar</a>";
        $loophtml = $loophtml . "</li>";
     }
```

Anyone knows how I add the content somewhere? Thanks

Comment: Elaborate on "cannot make it work". What happens? (And alternatively consider posting on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: For ref: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5600/how-do-i-display-the-function-the-content-in-this-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the post data are stored in the $question object, to retrieve the content

```
echo $question->post_content;
```

[Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) is some more information on get_post().

It has nothing to do with your question but please note: next_post() is deprecated.

Comment: Sorry I hadn't realized what you meant with next_post until now. I'd like to replace it so it works in the future. Could you tell me how can I replace that line so I don't use next_post? Thanks